# Installing Service via Share gets ignored from Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services, nservicebus

I'm trying to install the NServiceBus.Host.Exe on a Server from a local Script, which in it's easiest form is just a /Install. 
Just to test, what's happening, I shared the Server-Path, impersonated my Script as the Active Directory Admin-User and now I do:

```
\\Server\Integration\Publisher\NServiceBus.Host.exe /Install
```

Nothing happening here, no Info on the Log, that I tried to install. It seems like my /Install Command is totally ignored.
My second approach was to use the Install-Util. So I also shared the Path to the InstallUtil.exe and then the following Command:

```
\\Server\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe \\Server\Integration\\Publisher\NServiceBus.Host.exe
```

But also nothing happening.
I'm using the AD-Admin, so I have all rights to install such stuff, but it seems like it's not possible to install a Service on a Share or from another PC. My question: Is this a general Powershell/Services Problem or just a NServiceBus one?

Comment: Have you tried mapping the file share to a network drive using `net use` inside the script and using such a path instead? Are you installing the service on the same machine as the file share?

Comment: I'm not sure that a service can run over the network.  At best, it would be extremely unusual to do so.

Comment: Hm Thanks for the Infos, I will give the net use a try. I really didn't find any other solution to install the Services on the Server via PowerShell, I tried like all ideas I found.

Comment: Is the file server the same as the server that is supposed to run the NServiceBus host? Are you trying to automate deployment of NServiceBus endpoints (hosted by NServiceBus.Host) onto a remote server?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller Any luck getting this to work for you?

Comment: I found this little article, I thought it might be helpful http://www.ben-morris.com/deploying-a-windows-service-remotely-with-powershell/.

Comment: @MarcinHoppe: No, but I couldn't find a justification to put more effort into it but just installing the Service once manually. But I will for sure look into the Article, thanks.